# Ionic - How to get selected item in Ionic checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-model

I wanna get selected item in Ionic checkboxes. So, when user checks checkbox(es), I wanna know which book(s) he/she has selected.

Here are my code snippets:

```
        <ion-item ng-repeat="book in data.books">

                <div style="margin-left:110px;margin-right:10px;">
                    {{book.name}}
                </div>

                <li class="item item-checkbox  checkbox-balanced">

                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                    </label>
                </li>

            </ion-item>
```

When run the code, it looks like this:

[image]

I wanna use ng-model but I do not know how to use it. Can someone help me please as I am new to Ionic and AngularJS, THANKS!

**UPDATE**:
I am extremely sorry that I did not provide the controller's code snippet, here are the codes:

```
    .controller('DetailsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get("") // some webservice url
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.data = response.data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a variable for **`checked`** in each value and bind that as a **`model`** variable to the check box

**`DEMO`**

```js
var clubApp = angular.module('clubApp', ['ionic'])
clubApp.controller('ctrlPlayer', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.books = [{
    "name": "And the goog news is",
    "checked": false
    }, {
    "name": "Girl on the train",
    "checked": false
  }];
 $scope.getselected = function(){
    angular.forEach($scope.books,function(key,value){
        if(key.checked ==true)
        {
          alert(key.name);
        }
    });
 }

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='clubApp'>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/css/ionic.min.css">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.9/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.min.js"></script>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrlPlayer">
 <ion-list>
  <ion-checkbox ng-model=value.checked   ng-repeat="(key, value) in books">
  <span>{{value.name}}</span>   
  </ion-checkbox>
</ion-list>
 <button ng-click="getselected()" class="button button-positive">
            get selected
 </button>
  <h1>{{selectedval}}</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I am extremely sorry that I did not provide the controller's code. It is my mistake. I am sorry. I have updated the question with the label "UPDATE". Can you please take a look? Thank you Sajeetharan